# Users Group Expiration

Tags: expresso-store, members, simple-commerce

I have a use case where I would like an add-on or admin to set a users group with additional privileges and provide an expiration that would change the user back to their original group, or even a default group such as members.

The goal would be to allow members to purchase a "subscription" but not as recurring.

I assume this can be done with simple commerce, however from everything i have seen there is no way to allow and administrator to change or setup and expiration for teh group change.  Adding a transaction manually through Simple Commerce does not act as a subscription, and thus teh group change features will not work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lamb's add-on, among it's many other rather cool features, [Securit:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/securitee) includes an extension that does provide the amine the ability to auto-expire a member account within a given group after a set amount of time.  Might be worth a look.  I don't see mention of it changing the member from one group to another automatically though - just expiring the account.

Comment: Securit:ee does only allow expiration of accounts form my research, so was not applicable in my situation.